# How to use SxProps<Theme> of mui v5 to define a property of an interface and later use that in destructring?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to define an interface with a property (Let's say X) which is of type SxProps<Theme> used from @mui/material library.

I believe this property X must behave like an sx object and must support all the key values pairs sx of mui v5 offers. For example (height, ml, bgcolor etc.). But I receive following TypeScript error when I try to access the "height" key.

```
Property 'height' does not exist on type 'SystemCssProperties<Theme> | CSSPseudoSelectorProps<Theme> | CSSSelectorObjectOrCssVariables<Theme> | ((theme: Theme) => SystemStyleObject<...>) | readonly (boolean | ... 1 more ... | ((theme: Theme) => SystemStyleObject<...>))[]'.
  Property 'height' does not exist on type 'CSSPseudoSelectorProps<Theme>'.ts(2339)
any
```

I have a LayoutHeaderOptions interface defined as below:

```
import { SxProps, Theme } from '@mui/material';

interface LayoutHeaderOptions {
  hide: boolean;
  fixed: boolean;
  sx?: SxProps<Theme>;
}
```

Where I have defined sx property of type SxProps<Theme> and I have imported both SxProps and Theme from @mui/material.

Then I have defined another interface LayoutOptions like this:

```
interface LayoutOptions {
  header: LayoutHeaderOptions;  
}
```

After that another interface LayoutContext as mentioned below:

```
interface LayoutContext {  
  headerOptions: LayoutHeaderOptions;  
}
```

After that I'm defining a constant defaultLayoutOptions as below:

```
const defaultLayoutOptions: LayoutOptions = {
  header: {
    hide: false,
    fixed: true,
  },
}
```

After that I'm defining a constant defaultLayoutContext as below:

```
const defaultLayoutContext: LayoutContext = {  
  headerOptions: defaultLayoutOptions.header,
};

const MyLayoutContext = React.createContext(defaultLayoutContext);
```

After that a custom hook like this:

```
function useMyLayout() {
  return useContext(MyLayoutContext);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to utilize the headerOptions of the context value in another custom hook as below:

```
function useHeaderSpaceSx() {
  const { headerOptions } = useMyLayout();

  const headerHeightProps: SxProps<Theme> = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (headerOptions?.sx?.height) {
      return { height: headerOptions.sx.height };
    }
    return {};
  }, [headerOptions?.sx]);

  return headerHeightProps;
}
```

But when I try to access headerOptions?.sx?.height I receive a TypeScript error:

```
Property 'height' does not exist on type 'SystemCssProperties<Theme> | CSSPseudoSelectorProps<Theme> | CSSSelectorObjectOrCssVariables<Theme> | ((theme: Theme) => SystemStyleObject<...>) | readonly (boolean | ... 1 more ... | ((theme: Theme) => SystemStyleObject<...>))[]'.
  Property 'height' does not exist on type 'CSSPseudoSelectorProps<Theme>'.ts(2339)
any
```

I'm not sure what causing this error. Also, this is my first project in TypeScript so if you find a way to improve the above design, kindly suggest that too.